# How to open an external URL from FCM Notification for Flutter app (Android and iOS)?

Tags: flutter, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, apple-push-notifications, android-notifications

Is it possible to open a link by clicking on a notification sent by Firebase Cloud Messaging to a Flutter app (Android & iOS) while the app is closed? I am using Legacy HTTP Requests.

Answer (score 0):

it's possible! You need to write listener for background service, it's actually already in the firebase_messaging package. Then you need to write function for launch url from your FCM notification. Learn FLUTTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK

This is for example:

```
FirebaseMessaging.onMessageOpenedApp.listen((RemoteMessage message) {
      print('A new onMessageOpenedApp event was published!');
      currentBottomIndex = 2;
      goHome(context);
    });
```

Comment: Is this possible if the app is completely closed (not in background) ?

Comment: It is a Google service that works in the background without affecting the phone, so don't worry ;)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a workaround for launching urls from the background when the app has been removed from the background apps section.
Here, I'm using [firebase_core](https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_core), [firebase_messaging](https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_messaging) and [flutter_local_notifications](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_local_notifications) directory to handle notifications received from Firebase. I'm using the [url_launcher](https://pub.dev/packages/url_launcher) directory to redirect to the required URL.

For the firebase notification handler, we set the background notification handler as follows :

```
FirebaseMessaging.onBackgroundMessage(handleBackgroundMessage);
```

define the handleBackgroundMessage function outside any class or function, to be independent and global with the @pragma tag

```
Future<void> handleBackgroundMessage(RemoteMessage message) async {
  final Future<SharedPreferences> _prefs = SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  final SharedPreferences prefs = await _prefs;
  String video_url = message.data['video_url'].toString();
  if(video_url.isNotEmpty && video_url!='null') {
    var flag = await prefs.setString('KEY_LAUNCH_URL', video_url);
  }
}
```

Now we move to the main.dart or any Splash Screen pages that you might use. In my case, I use a stateful widget within EntryPage.dart file. Here, i define a custom function as follows :

```
void get_launch_url() async {
  final SharedPreferences prefs = await _prefs;
  String? video_url = prefs.getString('KEY_LAUNCH_URL');
  if(video_url!=null && video_url.toString().isNotEmpty) {
    launchUrl(Uri.parse(video_url.toString()));
    await prefs.setString('KEY_LAUNCH_URL', "");
  }
}
```

Now for the initState override method of the class inside EntryPage.dart, i call the above function

```
get_launch_url();
```

Note : This is a workaround that seems to work for me. You're basically storing your redirect url as a cache. When the notification is clicked, the app opens and it checks if the cache is present. If the redirect cache is neither null or empty, it tries to redirect to whatever url is provided as the redirect value.